# String compare in PHP - Keep returning wrong value

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress I'm using a plug in that logs a meta key _featured and adds a value of yes or no. I want to add css if it is featured, however it is adding the div no matter what the result.

```
            <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true ) ) : ?>
                <?php $feat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true ); ?>
                            <?php if( strcasecmp($feat, yes) == 0)?>
                                <a href=""><div class="featured_reject">Featured Rejection</div></a>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <h1><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true ) ?></h1>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Not all of this is intended for the end, some of it is just to test the results of the log.

```
            <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true ) ) : ?>
```

This checks if there is a value. Works fine.

```
<?php $feat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true ); ?>
```

Logging it as a variable

```
<?php if( strcasecmp($feat, 'yes') == 0)?>
                                    <a href=""><div class="featured_reject">Featured Rejection</div></a>

                                <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code to add the div. It adds it regardless of whether the value is yes or no.

```
<h1><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_featured', true ) ?></h1>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

This last portion is simply to check what the value is for myself.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: I personally dislike strcasecmp.  I would use `strtolower($feat) == 'yes'` for my comparison

Comment: @cale_b Yeahhh I' having massive issues with this string comparison stuff. I have two string comparisons on the page and both are broken as all hell. I tried $feat === 'yes' and strcmp($feat, 'yes') neither works.

Comment: So what does `var_dump($feat)` output? You should use var_dump instead of echo to see the contents of a variable - it gives you the type of variable and other useful information.

Comment: It outputs yes or no depending on the status. And thank you for the tip. There has to be something wrong with my if argument, I changed the variable to a string length and then changed the if argument to >2. Still prints each time.

Comment: in your first code paste there are no single quotes around yes, can you confirm it is always in single quotes. Can you paste the output of var_dump($feat) here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML isn't wrapped in PHP and thus isn't affected by the conditional statement

Change

```
<?php if( strcasecmp($feat, 'yes') == 0)?>
                                    <a href=""><div class="featured_reject">Featured Rejection</div></a>

                                <?php endif; ?>
```

to

```
<?php 
  if(strcasecmp($feat, 'yes') == 0){
       echo "<a href = ''><div class = 'featured_reject'>Featured Rejection</div></a>"
  }
?>
```

Comment: Or my preference is to actually put the : at the end of the of statement (or use {} for wrapping)

Comment: This was the correct answer. For some reason I thought it would treat it the ?php if and endif as a wrapper and execute the code between that if it was true. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickCauley - it will.  You understood it right.  I suspect it's the lack of curly brace or colon at the end of the `if` line.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the php if..endif is:

```
if (condition):
   ...
endif;
```

(per: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php )

So you need to change

```
<?php if( strcasecmp($feat, yes) == 0)?>
    <a href=""><div class="featured_reject">Featured Rejection</div></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to (note the extra : after ==) in the if statement:

```
<?php if( strcasecmp($feat, yes) == 0):?>
    <a href=""><div class="featured_reject">Featured Rejection</div></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: and I just saw the comments from jdog to the answer by Lloyd Banks. I think my only reaction is going to be "what he said..."